# Im Trying to link the thumbnail image

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I am trying to link my thumbnail image that is displayed by the list-category-post plugin on this page...
http://elizabeth.vernetti.com/featured-properties/

I am using a custom template and have managed to get it linked to "#" using this code.

```
 //Post Thumbnail
$lcp_display_output .= '<a href="#">';
$lcp_display_output .= $this->get_thumbnail($single);
$lcp_display_output .= '</a>';
```

I know there is a way to use the_permalink to link it properly to the right post but I haven't been able to figure out the right syntax... i don't have much programming background.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried replacing get_thumbnail with:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.19.1 of [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/), the thumbnail links to the post.